# How to add eventhub jar or library file in Zeppelin?

Tags: azure

When attempting:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils
```

I'm getting the error:

```
object eventhubs is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
```

I tried adding the jar file spark-streaming_2.10-1.5.1.jar using the command:

```
z.load("/jars/spark-streaming_2.10-1.5.1.jar")
```

my jar file was placed in `hdfs` folder under `jar` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if spark-streaming_2.10-1.5.1.jar file has the org.apache.spark.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils class in it. (you can rename it to zip file or using jar -tvf check the same). When i download the file from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10/1.5.1 
i do not see the class in the jar.

You can download the spark-streaming-eventhubs jar file from below location

https://github.com/hdinsight/hdinsight-spark-examples/tree/master/sparkstreaming/lib

and i can see that this jar has the required class. Also i imported through spark-shell and it works fine when i run import statement so it should work in zeppelin too.

Answer (score 0):

No still I face the issue even when the required class is the jar file.

Is there a way to make zeppelin understand the class files in the external jar?

I have also spark.files option in SPARK_HOME/spark-client/conf/spark-defaults.conf.

But still I face the same issue.